# Creating a list of N numbers from existing list each repeated K times

Tags: python, list, repeat

I believe this is an easy problem to solve. I have searched and found a few similar answers but not an efficient way to exactly what I want to achieve.

Assuming the following list:

```python
x = [6, 7, 8]
```

I want to create a new list by repeating each number k times. Assuming k=3, the result should be:

```python
xr = [6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8]
```

I was able to accomplish this using nest loops, which I believe is very inefficient:

```python
xr = []
for num in x: # for each number in the list
    for t in range(3): # repeat 3 times
        xx2.append(num)
```

I also tried:

```python
[list(itertools.repeat(x[i], 3)) for i in range(len(x))]
```

but I get:

```python
[[6, 6, 6], [7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8]]
```

Is there a more efficient direct method to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, everyone for the answers.

It seems there is an easier and more direct way to solve this using Numpy.

```python
np.repeat(x, 3).tolist()
```

prints exactly what I needed:

```python
[6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension:

```py
x = [6, 7, 8]
k = 3

out = [v for v in x for _ in range(k)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def repeat_k(l,k):
    lo = []
    for x in l:
        for i in range(k):
            lo.append(x)
    return lo

print (repeat_k([1,2,3],5))
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

With list comprehension:

```
def repeat_k(l,k):
    return [ x for x in l for i in range(k) ]

print (repeat_k([1,2,3],5))
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
>>> x = [6, 7, 8]
>>> k = 3
>>> l = []
>>> for item in x:
...     l += k * [item]
...
>>> l
[6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a convenient function:

```
def repeat(it, n):
    for elem in it: yield from [elem] * n
```

Use it like:

```
>>> list(repeat(x, n=3))
[6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
x=[4,5,6]
k=3
res = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(i, K) for i in test_list))
print (res)
```

It can also be solved using python inbuilt functions of itertools library. The repeat function does the task of repetition and grouping into a list is done by the from_iterable function.